# Unable to find mkoctfile in expected location, windows warning

Tags: c++, c, compilation, octave

I want to compile C library in Octave 3.6.2 I have working on windows 7 64-bits. I want to compile this library with VS compiler, because I have in library part of code supported COM port on the windows. 
When I compile library, I get an error

```c++
warning: unable to find mkoctfile in expected location: `C:\Program Files (x
86)\Octave-3.6.2\bin\mkoctfile-3.6.2'
warning: mkoctfile exited with failure status
```

but I have this file in my folder. 
I had spended many hour on this problem, and I didnt solved this.
And advice?

Comment: _"but I have this file in my folder"_ Does _your folder_ differ from the specified one in the error message?

Comment: This is path where I have mkoctfile "C:\Program Files (x86)\Octave-3.6.2\bin". So this is the same path in console. When I execute "mkoctfile -h" in Octave all working well.